# Can the discontinuities in this function be removed?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

## Question

I have a long equation for a function $f(u, v)$, and I want to get rid of a set of discontinuities that exist at the lines $u = \frac{3}{2} + 4n$ and $v = \frac{3}{2} + 4n$ for integer values of $n$. The function is symmetric in $u$ and $v$, so for simplification I have used that fact to pull out several repeated chunks as two helper sub-functions.

The function appears to have well-defined two-sided limits around both sets of discontinuities, which makes me think they are removable discontinuities. The discontinuities exist because the denominator of the function equals zero for those input values. However, I haven't been able to find a way to factor or rearrange the function to eliminate the division by zero.

The function also has periodic infinite discontinuities where a limit does not exist, which suggests to me that they definitely aren't removable.

Is it possible re-write the function $f(u, v)$ as a single, non-piecewise equation that lacks the linear discontinuities at $u = \frac{3}{2} + 4n$ and $v = \frac{3}{2} + 4n$?

## The Equations

$$f(u, v) = \frac{2g(u) g(v)\ ((2 + \sqrt{2}) (g(v) h(u) + g(u) h(v)) + (2 - \sqrt{2})\ h(u)\ h(v))}{3h(u)^2 (g(v)^2 + h(v)^2) + (g(v)\ h(u) + 2 g(u)\ h(v))^2}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{12} − \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{3} \frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{π}{2}x\right) + \sqrt{2} + 4} \left(3 \sin\left(\frac{π}{2}x\right) + \cos\left(\frac{π}{2}x\right)\right)$$

$$h(x) = \frac{4 \sqrt{3} + 3\sqrt{6}}{6} − \frac{8\sqrt{3} + 6\sqrt{6}}{3} \frac{1}{2\cos\left(\frac{π}{2}x\right) + \sqrt{2} + 4}$$

Comment: Are you sure $f(u,v) = f(v,u)$, the denominator doesn't look symmetric to me. Desmos graph doesnt seem to match your description: https://www.desmos.com/3d/4958af1076

Comment: @CalvinKhor To your first point, when you plot the function, notice that it is symmetrical about the plane $v = u$ (or $y = x$). To your second point, interestingly, Desmos appears to be hiding or removing the discontinuities, but you can confirm they exist by evaluating the denominator with either $u$ or $v$ set to $\frac{3}{2} + 4 n$. The discontinuities are more apparent in GeoGebra, which does a poorer job of rendering a 3D graph with discontinuities than Desmos apparently does.

Comment: OK, I assumed the graph was wrong because there were other singularities than what you described. Looking at the numerator and denominator separately there's a lot of cancellation. I made some horrible sympy code which I think showed numerator and denominator are 0 to third order. At the fourth order there is finally cancellation to the constant $\displaystyle - \frac{91}{102} + \frac{5 \sqrt{2}}{68}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry, I hadn't mentioned the other singularities because I didn't think they were removable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that $$u = \frac32+4u' \qquad v = \frac32+4v' \qquad\left(\text{and }\; x = \frac32+4x'\right)$$
(The singularities of concern for $f(u,v)$ happen when $u'$ and $v'$ are integers.) Then we can simplify
$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= \phantom{-}\sin(\pi x')\;\frac{\sqrt6 \left(\;\cos(\pi x'+\pi_4) + 
   12c^2 \sin(\pi x'+\pi_4) \;\right)}{12\;\left(\;1 - 
   \cos(\pi x' + \pi_4) \sin(\pi x') \;\right)} \\[8pt]
h(x) &= -\sin(\pi x')\;\frac{4\sqrt6\;c^4 \cos(\pi x' + \pi_4) }{
 3 \left(\;1 - \cos(\pi x' + \pi_4) \sin(\pi x') \;\right)}
\end{align}$$
where $\pi_n := \pi/n$ is a bit of notation I often invoke to avoid having to write fractions of $\pi$, and
$$s := \sin\pi_8 = \frac12\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} \qquad c := \cos\pi_8 = \frac12\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$$
Having factored-out $\sin(\pi x')$ bodes well for removing the singularities. Indeed, we find the reduced form
$$\begin{align}
f(u,v) &= -\frac23s^4\;\frac{G(u)G(v)\;\cos(\pi(u'+v'))}{
 \left(\;\begin{array}{c}
   1 - \sin(\pi u'+\pi_4) \sin(\pi v'+\pi_4) \sin(\pi(u'+v')) \\
    + 2s^2\cos(\pi u'+\pi_4) \cos(\pi v'+\pi_4) \cos(\pi(u'+v'))
   \end{array}\;\right)} \tag{$\star$}\\[8pt]
G(x) &= \cos(\pi x'+\pi_4) + 12c^2 \sin(\pi x'+\pi_4)
\end{align}$$
is defined when $u'$ and/or $v'$ are integers. For instance,
$$\begin{align}
f(0,v) &= -\frac23 s^4
  (1 + 12 c^2)
  \;\frac{G(v) \cos(\pi v')}{
    \sqrt{2} - \sin(\pi v' + \pi_4) \sin(\pi v')
     + 2 s^2 \cos(\pi v' + \pi_4) \cos(\pi v')
    } \\[8pt]
f(0,0) &= -\frac13 \frac{s^4 (1 + 12 c^2)^2}{1 + s^2}
\end{align}$$

As a bonus, $(\star)$ makes clear that $f(u,v)=f(v,u)$, which isn't at all obvious in the original expression.

Writing $f(u,v)$ in terms of $u'$ and $v'$ seems convenient, but to restore $u$ and $v$ themselves, simply replace
$$u'+v' = \frac14(u+v-3) \qquad\qquad \pi x' +\pi_4 = \frac\pi8(2x-1)$$

---

**Addendum.** Below is *Mathematica*'s plot of OP's version of the function, and mine, showing that they coincide (except, of course, at removable singularities). The splotchy blue and orange represent noise in the numerical calculations.

[image]

Comment: I tried entering your (⋆) equation for $f(u, v)$ in my GeoGebra file for this project, and its graph doesn't match the graph of my original function. What might I be missing that's making it go wrong?

Comment: @Lawton: I couldn't tell you what's causing the discrepancies in GeoGebra, but I've added a plot from *Mathematica* indicating that the functions do indeed match. (I've also re-checked the symbolic calculations a couple of times.) You could try testing in GeoGebra whether your versions of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ match mine; they *should*, but if GeoGebra isn't showing that, then it may be easier to spot the problem. (Maybe a typo crept in to my answer, but I'm not seeing it at the moment.)

Comment: I went through your math step-by-step and found a typo that was causing the graphs-not-matching problem: $π x' + π_4 = \frac{π}{8}(2 x - 1)$, not $\frac{π}{4}(2 x - 1)$. After fixing that, both graphs line up perfectly aside from the removable singularity! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lawton: Ah ... A typo in my very last equation. I was *so close!* :) ... I've made the correction. ... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $n=0$ by periodicity. I made some horrible sympy code which I think showed numerator and denominator are 0 to third order. At the fourth order there is finally cancellation to the constant $c=- \frac{91}{102} + \frac{5 \sqrt{2}}{68}$, so the singularity is removable. Its very bad code but it matches with [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/3d/060c87002d) (the sphere is at $(3/2,3/2,c)$ and the contour line is $f=c$):
[image]

What the below code does: if $f=n/d$ is the function in question (clearly $n,d$ are smooth functions) then the below computes the 4th order Taylor expansion (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions)) around $p_0=(3/2,3/2)$ of the numerator $n$ and denominator $d$. (Commenting out the 4th order derivatives one can show that the 3rd order terms and below vanish.) Then it verifies that $T^4_{p_0} n/T^4_{p_0} d = c$. It follows therefore that as $p\to p_0$,
$$ f(p) = \frac{n(p)}{d(p)} = \frac{T^4_{p_0} n(p) + o(|p-p_0|^4)}{T^4_{p_0} d(p) + o(|p-p_0|^4)} = c + o(1).$$

```
# Import sympy and define symbols
import sympy as sp


u, v, n = sp.symbols("u v n")

# Define sub-functions g(x) and h(x)
def g(x: sp.Expr) -> sp.Expr:
    return (2 * sp.sqrt(3) + sp.sqrt(6)) / 12 - (sp.sqrt(3) + sp.sqrt(6)) / 3 * 1 / (
        2 * sp.cos(sp.pi / 2 * x) + sp.sqrt(2) + 4
    ) * (3 * sp.sin(sp.pi / 2 * x) + sp.cos(sp.pi / 2 * x))


def h(x: sp.Expr) -> sp.Expr:
    return (4 * sp.sqrt(3) + 3 * sp.sqrt(6)) / 6 - (
        8 * sp.sqrt(3) + 6 * sp.sqrt(6)
    ) / 3 * 1 / (2 * sp.cos(sp.pi / 2 * x) + sp.sqrt(2) + 4)


# Define main function f(u, v)
def f(u: sp.Expr, v: sp.Expr):
    return (
        2
        * g(u)
        * g(v)
        * (
            (2 + sp.sqrt(2)) * (g(v) * h(u) + g(u) * h(v))
            + (2 - sp.sqrt(2)) * h(u) * h(v)
        )
        / (
            3 * h(u) ** 2 * (g(v) ** 2 + h(v) ** 2)
            + (g(v) * h(u) + 2 * g(u) * h(v)) ** 2
        )
    )


# Split the function into numerator and denominator
num, den = f(u, v).as_numer_denom()

x0 = sp.Rational(3, 2)


def evalx0(expr: sp.Expr):
    return expr.subs(u, x0).subs(v, x0)


taylor_terms = []
for expr in [num, den]:
    out = evalx0(expr)
    for diffwrt in [
        (u,),
        (v,),
        (u, u),
        (u, v),
        (v, u),
        (v, v),
        (u, u, u),
        (u, u, v),
        (u, v, u),
        (u, v, v),
        (v, u, u),
        (v, u, v),
        (v, v, u),
        (v, v, v),
        (u, u, u, u),
        (u, u, u, v),
        (u, u, v, u),
        (u, u, v, v),
        (u, v, u, u),
        (u, v, u, v),
        (u, v, v, u),
        (u, v, v, v),
        (v, u, u, u),
        (v, u, u, v),
        (v, u, v, u),
        (v, u, v, v),
        (v, v, u, u),
        (v, v, u, v),
        (v, v, v, u),
        (v, v, v, v),
    ]:
        l = len(diffwrt)
        prod = sp.Integer(1)
        for val in diffwrt:
            prod = prod * (val - x0)
        out = out + evalx0(expr.diff(*diffwrt)) * prod / sp.factorial(l)
    taylor_terms.append(out)

num_lead = taylor_terms[0].simplify()
denom_lead = taylor_terms[1].simplify()
fcomb_lead = num_lead/denom_lead
fcomb_lead.simplify()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "numerator and denominator are 0 to third order"? I'm not familiar with sympy, and the Wikipedia page you linked is going way over my head. Can you add the version of the function you came up with that has the singularities removed?

Comment: @Lawton, every smooth function can be approximated as a Taylor series $$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!} + \frac{f^{(3)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^3}{3!} + \dots$$. This is also basically true in higher dimensions (here dimension is 2). The computation only proves (without getting a new version) that the singularity is removable and that if you are close to $(3/2,3/2)$, then the function is close to the constant $c$. By "0 to third order" I mean that the first nonzero term in the Taylor expansion looks like $k(x-x_0)^4$, which is "quite flat near $x_0$".

Comment: Is there a way for me to use this proof that the singularity is removable to actually remove the singularity?

Comment: @Lawton, what do you mean by actually remove the singularity? In the same way you can remove the singularity for $\sin x/x$ by defining the value at $x=0$ to be 1, you can define
$f(p) =\begin{cases} \text{formula in your question}  & p \neq (3/2,3/2) \\ c & p = (3/2,3/2) \end{cases}$
and the above shows this is continuous.

The Taylor approximation gives you a good approximation near the troublesome point ($p=(3/2,3/2)$), precisely that $f(p) = c + R(p)$ where $|R(p)| \to 0$ as $x\to p$.There is a precise formula for $R(p)$ but it is not useful (it doesn't even fit in this comment box)

Comment: I want to find a single (non-piecewise) equation that is equal to my original function everywhere except for the lines of discontinuity in the original function, where it is actually continuous.

Comment: @Lawton yes, this does not let you do that, which is what I meant when I said "(without getting a new version)". This does however prove that it is a removable singularity.